# How to override iterator `next()` to return Set<E> rather than E?

Tags: java, iterator

I am in a certain scenario where I want to return a `Set<E>` rather than a `E` from next function in an iterator. Is there any design pattern / known fix, to work around such a scenario ?

To explain my usecase, I am writing a code to `join all levels of a tree` more details [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/connect-nodes-at-same-level-with-o1-extra-space/):
Now I want an iterator whose `next()` would return a set of all nodes in that row, then the next row, and then the next row till last.

Any pointers to proceed ?

Comment: You have to create an `Iterator<Set<E>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a

```
List<Set<E>>
```

and iterate through that.